# Regex specific Param from Uri

Tags: regex

Simply put, I pull the href prop of a link and need to replace it with new link when clicked. The new link needs 1 parameter from the original link (a claim link opening a new window and claiming a task for a user).

Thus far I have a ***working*** solution. What I'm wanting is for someone to maybe help me refine my **RegEx** a little.

For links like:

```
/crm/v2/claimTask?email=example@gmail.com&id=1372365392-1UsIvb-0002qr-Sz
```

I use:

```
$(this).prop("href").match(/(email|order|phone|num)=\s*?(.+)&/)[0].replace(/&/, '')
```

And get:

```
email=example@gmail.com
```

What i'd like to do is be able to remove `.replace(/&/, '')` and have the regex stop at the `&` symbol to begin with, but i'm unsure how to do this. Any ideas?

Further examples:

```
/crm/v2/claimTask?order=123456&id=137236456452-1UweRRwvb-00456jr-Sz
/crm/v2/claimTask?phone=6665554444&id=175655392-4WERTe4-097qt-Da
/crm/v2/claimTask?num=6665554444&id=1372234392-9sfaWa-12374ip-eW
/crm/v2/claimTask?email=email@test.net&id=133453465392-k0wS24S-36735qr-rt
```

Using:

```
$(this).prop("href").match(/(email|order|phone|num)=\s*?(.+)&/)
```

Would yield:

```
order=123456&
phone=6665554444&
num=6665554444&
email=email@test.net&
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a lookahead:
`(email|order|phone|num)=\s*?(.+)(?=&)`

It will not "eat" the ampersand.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(this).prop("href").match(/((email|order|phone|num)=\s*?(.+))&/)[1] //"email=email@test.net"
$(this).prop("href").match(/((email|order|phone|num)=\s*?(.+))&/)[3] //"email@test.net"
```

The above just puts the part without the `&` into a capture group. You could also use a positive lookahead:

```
$(this).prop("href").match(/(email|order|phone|num)=\s*?(.+)(?=&)/) //["email=email@test.net", "email", "email@test.net"]
```